# Excel VBA change data souce based on reference value

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I can not manage to figure out how to change the data source of pivot table with VBA.

I have the data source in Sheet1 and the pivot in Sheet 2

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
sNewSource = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A19:X" & LastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache _
  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
  SourceData:=sNewSource, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

At the moment I'm getting an error message: Unable to get the PivotTables properly of the Worksheet class

I tried looking at other solutions, but I can not figure out where it is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your comment in one of the answer below, are you changing the data source because of dynamic data? If yes, first create a name range which will handle dynamic data and then use it for Pivot table.

Comment: why is SourceData:=sNewSource not working thogh?

Comment: So what happened when you try both the options given in answers...?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a *direct* answer to your question, more an opportunity to explain how it could possibly be done better.

All of these options involve creating a *named range* or *table name*, which you would use as the data source for your pivot table

## Option 1

Give your data a named range and get VBA to update that named range

```
With ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("myRange")
    .RefersTo = Range(.RefersToRange, .RefersToRange.End(xlDown))
End With
```

## Option 2

Give your data a *dynamic named range*. The source reference might look like this:

```
=OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(A:A),COUNTA(1:1))
```

*Note, `OFFSET` is a volatile function and will slow down bigger workbooks*

## Option 3

Put your data into a *Data Table*. When you format your data as a *Table* excel will automatically resize when you add new data below

Answer (score 0):

Problems often arise when using `Select` and `ActiveSheet`. You have tried to access a PivotTable on Sheet1 when there are likely no PivotTables on Sheet1 (as you said, your PivotTable is on Sheet2).

This can be addressed by fully qualifying your references -- that means being explicit about which workbook and which worksheet you wish to use.

With that in mind, does this work? (untested)

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    sNewSource = .Name & "!" & .Range("A19:X" & LastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=sNewSource, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
End With
```

Comment: change `.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row` to `.Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I get another error message: object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @CallumDA i think he wants to have the `PivotTable` in the same sheet, "Sheet1" , maybe he doesn't have "Sheet2" ?

Comment: I'm pretty confused now. It reads like he has his PT in Sheet2 and data in Sheet1 (pretty much a quote). By the looks of his code he wants to update the pivot table with the latest data as it gets added to the bottom of his data in Sheet1? @Selrac, are you able to clarify?

Comment: The data in Sheet 1 will have some time more rows and sometime less rows. I tis not the case as data will be added to the bottom. I'm not sure what difference will it make though to the code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice. In the end I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select ' Data Source
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
sNewSource = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:B" & LastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
sNewSource = "C:\xxx\[test.xlsm]" & sNewSource

Sheets("Sheet2").Select ' Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=sNewSource, Version:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14)
```